# How to call a gradle task from productflavor

Tags: android, android-studio, jenkins, gradle

I need to enable Fabric for different build environments and also take into account whether the apk has been built using Android Studio or a CI server (jenkins) in our case.
Approach that I am thinking of using is:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.pack.proj"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 12
    ext.buildNumber = System.getenv("BUILD_NUMBER") ?: "dev"
    versionName "1.2.$buildNumber"
    signingConfig signingConfigs.inspection
}

productFlavors {
        dev1 {
            resValue 'string', 'app_name', 'App Name'
            resValue 'string', 'base_url', 'http://dev1.server.in/'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'USE_FABRIC', 'true'

        }
        dev2 {
            resValue 'string', 'app_name', 'App Name'
            resValue 'string', 'base_url', 'http://dev2.server.in/'
            // ********HOW DO I CALL THE TASK 'enableFabric' FROM HERE*********
        }
}

task enableFabric{
    if(versionName.contains('dev'))
        buildConfigField 'boolean', 'USE_FABRIC', 'false'
    else
        buildConfigField 'boolean', 'USE_FABRIC', 'true'
}
```

Now my questions are

1. How do I call the task enableFabric from dev1 and dev2 product
   flavors?
2. And when I run the gradle script I get the error that versionName is unrecognised property in task enableFabric?
3. also `buildConfigField 'boolean', 'USE_FABRIC', 'true'` when used in the defaultConfig does not work for me. when I use

   if(BuildConfig.USE_FABRIC == true){
      // DO something
   }

in the Java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the if else directly in dev2. or if you plan to use it more than once turn it into a function instead of task

example:

```
productFlavors {
    dev1 {
        resValue 'string', 'app_name', 'App Name'
        resValue 'string', 'base_url', 'http://dev1.server.in/'
        buildConfigField 'boolean', 'USE_FABRIC', 'true'

    }
    dev2 {
        resValue 'string', 'app_name', 'App Name'
        resValue 'string', 'base_url', 'http://dev2.server.in/'
        buildConfigField 'boolean', 'USE_FABRIC', useFabric()
    }
}
```

outside of your `android` block, do something like

```
def useFabric() {
    if (versionName.contains('dev')) 
       return false;
    else return true;
}
```

Comment: I dont want to do it in dev2 directly because I have 20 other environments as well. Also, if you could explain using an example/sample code.

Comment: sorry for the late response but BuildConfig.USE_FABRIC shows an unknown variable compilation error.